# ¿Cómo definimos una fruta que está muy madura pero sin estar podrida, al límite de lo comible?

Tags: adjetivos, solicitud-de-término

En catalán usamos la palabra *lloca* para definir aquella fruta que está demasiado madura y cogió un color oscuro, como si estuviera podrida. A veces es pastosa, a veces esponjosa. Aún se puede comer, pero ya no es apetecible.

He aquí una imagen al respecto que encontré:

[image]

Estuve pensando y no se me ocurrió ninguna palabra equivalente en castellano. ¿La tenemos?

En catalán, [*lloca*](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0083607) también designa a una ave en su período de empollar. Curiosamente, la traducción que me da google translate a *lloca* es *clueca*, que la RAE define como:

> [**clueco, ca**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9VM1c3C)
>   De *clocar*.
>   1. adj. Dicho de una gallina o de otra ave: Que está en el período de empollar los huevos. U. t. c. s. f.
>   2. adj. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Muy débil y casi impedida por la vejez.

Viendo la segunda acepción pienso que tal vez *clueco, ca* podría ser la palabra que busco, si la aplicamos a una fruta en lugar de una persona. Sin embargo, nunca la oí en este contexto.

Comment: En la España rural alguna vez he oído que a la fruta «le ha cantado el cuco». Tirando de ese hilo he visto que en gallego se dice «cucar» tanto para el acto de cantar ese pájaro como para envejecer. También se usa «croquear» (croar el sapo) para el fruto que se pudre o _empieza_ a pudrirse. No encuentro nada para el castellano al respecto.

Comment: @guillem En Aragón también podríamos decir que la fruta está *cucada*, pero nos referiríamos más bien a que tiene algún golpe. Una manzana, por ejemplo, puede estar *cucada* por tener alguna marca dejada por un golpe, pero no estaría necesariamente muy madura.

Comment: @Gorpik me da la sensación de que ese «cucada» aragonés no viene del cuco pájaro, sino del cuco gusano, al igual que la «cuquera» (gusanera) para referirse a una herida, ¿puede ser?

Comment: En efecto, de ahí viene.

Comment: Ni pasada, ni pachucho, ni pachichi funcionan por aquí. Nosotros decimos está **remadura** (re-madura ¿?) o  está **muy madura**

Comment: Mi abuelo usa una palabra que no sé si sea náhuatl y no tengo idea de como se escribe, es algo como palachkle, palaxcle, palashcle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Buscando en el DIRAE me he encontrado con una palabra que me resulta muy graciosa y familiar, y que encaja con lo que buscas: **[pachucho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RPWTFER)**.

> 1. adj. Pasado de puro maduro.

Por tanto, se puede decir que una fruta está pachucha cuando se está empezando a estropear pero aún se puede comer, al igual que una persona está pachucha cuando no está enferma pero va camino de estarlo. Es una expresión que no me resulta desconocida, creo que recuerdo a mi abuela usándola.

Curiosamente, también he encontrado una palabra muy parecida que se usa en México: **[pachichi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RP1Fdsj)**.

> Del náhuatl *pachichina*, de *chichina* 'chupar'.
>
> 1. adj. Méx. Dicho de un fruto: Demasiado maduro.

Otra expresión que me sale sola cuando veo fruta así es decir que está **[pocha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TTHlYJ6)**:

> 1. adj. Dicho de un alimento, especialmente de la fruta: Podrida o dañada.

Comment: Caramba, conocía _pachucho_ para definir a alguien que está mal de salud, qué bueno que también sirva para definir fruta, en este caso.

Comment: Jamas habia oido pachuco y vivi toda mi vida en Mexico, (Baja california, Sonora, Sinaloa) probable sea regional de otros lugares o nomas nunca me toco que la usaran

Comment: "me resulta muy graciosa y familiar, y que encaja con lo que buscas" No se puede recomendar una palabra (por más que figure en el DRAE) si los hablantes, en general, no la conocen.

Comment: @leonbloy hay muchas diferencias entre los diversos países hispanohablantes en cuanto a expresiones se refiere. En este caso, _pachucho_ es un término común en España. Para mí es de uso habitual, aunque no tal vez con la acepción que nos atañe. Entiendo que en otros países no se use, pero no por ello debo dejar de recomendarla. Con el término _pachichi_ sí reconozco que me he aventurado. Por otro lado, no pasa nada si no conocemos algunos términos, siempre hay lugar para aprender expresiones nuevas que no conociésemos previamente.

Comment: ¡Me quedo con _pocha_!

Answer (score 11):

Lo de la foto es fruta **pasada**.

Hay una acepción en el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S33P1kX):

> 57. prnl. Dicho de la fruta, de la carne o de algo semejante: Perder la sazón o empezarse a pudrir.

Comment: Mmmm [yeah but no but yeah but...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tsl7-TJtPew) _Pasada_ implica que ya hay podredumbre. ¿no hay algún adjetivo para cuando aún no empezó a pudrirse aún?

Comment: @fedorqui te he buscado una alternativa a _pasada_ en mi respuesta, pero por aquí coincidimos en que hablar de "fruta pasada" sí es válido. A mi mujer es lo primero que se le ha ocurrido cuando se lo he comentado. Puedes entender "empezarse a pudrir" como "va camino de pudrirse", pero eso no implica que haya dejado de poder comerse.

Comment: @fedorqui would _pasanda_ be better or can you not use that as an adjective?

Comment: @mdewey _pasanda_ does not sound like a correct word to me.

Comment: @mdewey - Maybe you heard someone say "Se est'a pasando"?

Answer (score 5):

El uso que yo conozco, en diferentes lugares de España (tengo familia distribuida por aquí y por allá):

> Está **pasada** o **picada**.

Y también podemos decir está **tocada** sobre todo si es el resultado de haber recibido algún golpe.

Comment: "Picada" me suena totalmente, es un acierto, pero no estoy seguro de que se use en todas partes. En Chile _picada_ se entiende sin problemas; _tocada_, no estoy seguro. Por favor edita tu respuesta para aclarar en qué parte se usan esas palabras.

Comment: Es curioso, a mí _picada_ me suena más bien a cuando tiene un golpe, o más aún cuando tiene un agujero por el que se pueda haber colado un bicho. Es decir, no tiene que ver con el estado de madurez, sino con un daño concreto.

Comment: En Chile, por ejemplo, un melón "picado" está un poquito agrio, incluso picante, de color más oscuro y textura blanda. O sea, ya se pasó de fecha. La palabra sirve para hablar sobre todo de frutas, pero también del vino, del queso y del yogur.

Answer (score 4):

**Pasada** es también la palabra que he usado y oído usar siempre para referirse a fruta que está demasiado madura.

Por ejemplo:

> Estos plátanos están **pasados**, solo sirven para hacer batidos.

Answer (score 3):

Quería contribuir con una palabra que quizás no es más precisa que otras que se han dicho pero guarda cierta relación, se trata de:

> [modorro](https://dle.rae.es/modorro)
>
> 3. adj. Dicho de una fruta: Que pierde el color y empieza a fermentar.

Por lo que se podría decir: «ese plátano está modorro».

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa sería [**tocada**](https://dle.rae.es/tocado):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> [**en su punto**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UgMIq14)
>
> 1. loc. adj. En el estado de perfección que le corresponde.

Definición: DRAE Diccionário de la Real Academia Española

Por ejemplo: *Está fruta está en su punto*.

La pregunta es: una fruta que está madura pero sin estar podrida.

Después de estar en su punto, se pudre.

Por ejemplo lo veo usado en el artículo [Frutas de verano: cómo saber si están *en su punto*](https://www.miarevista.es/hogar/truco/como-saber-si-una-sandia-o-un-melon-estan-en-su-punto-981470211331).

Es una expresión muy común, y me arriesgo a decir que se diría en cualquier país hispanohablante.

Comment: Gracias por ofrecer una hipótesis. No comparto la idea pues _en su punto_ es un estado de _perfección_, cuando lo que yo consulto es por un estado _posterior_ a esa perfección, cuando ya cuesta comerla. Por otra parte, sería bueno que referenciaras de forma correcta, enlazando y citando.

Comment: @fedorqui Cuando uno cita algo de la RAE, creo que decirlo es suficiente (como se acepta en los otros sitos de SE sin problema). Fue mi única definición.  Y veo que me estás diciendo que las respuestas (pasada o picada,'pachucho) todas quiren decir ¿"muy madura pero sin estar podrida? A mi me parece que la foto muestra fruta que **ya se está pudriendo**. Y tres respuestas repitan el mismo término sin ninguna referencia y solo la de Charlie tiene un enlace. ¿A estas personas has hecho el mismo comentario que a mi? Creo que "en su punto" viene justo antes de "pudrido".

Comment: Me parece que tu pregunta y que tu foto no coinciden.

Comment: Creo que fedorqui busca una palabra para describir la fruta que ya pasó de su punto pero que todavía se puede comer, que no da asco.  Por ejemplo, estoy imaginando un plátano con precio descontado, con etiqueta "Ready for Banana Bread".

Comment: @aparente001 La pregunta dice: ***está muy madura sin estar pudrida***. Todas las respuestas excepto la mía hablan de fruta pudrida o dan un regionalismo. Hay que saber lo que uno quiere: ***verde, madura, en su punto (justo antes de pudrir) y pudrida***. No entiendo toda esta negatividad....me parece que los comentários no se justifiquen. En todo caso, en la foto se ve fruta pudriendo. Hay que saber lo que uno quiere.

Comment: Lambie: ya hemos comentado en anteriores ocasiones sobre cómo referenciar el material. Observa tu versión inicial https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/30584/revisions, donde no quedaba claro qué era cita. Más info en [How to reference material written by others](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Lo que yo busco/buscaba es un nombre para definir algo aún comestible, pero fuera de su punto ideal. Por ejemplo las peras a veces están arenosas cuando dejan de estar deliciosas. Por cierto, decimos _podrida_ :)

Comment: @fedorqui A dictionary definition with the name of the dictionary is enough on ELU and ELL. A dictionary definition is not writing, as in a paper or book. If you don't agree with me, please post the question on some meta site. On ELU, they cite the OED all the time, and it is behind a paywall. That was point one. Point two,  your question and the picture do not cohere. The picture shows rotting fruit, and the question says: still edible. So then, you pick on me, but accept all the answers about rotting fruit. I guess different rules apply to me. If you don't like my answer that's fine.

Comment: But nitpicking my answer and not the others is not so fine. By the way, no one on the other sites has ever complained about a definition given along with the name of the dictionary and no link. The RAE or DRAE is known to everyone. I always give the source dictionary. Also, when I use my paper dictionaries, I cannot provide a link, fyi. It's printed on paper. Actually, I forgot to mention the DRAE so I have now put it in.

Comment: Didn't you get anything out of [the previous debate in Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2996/1674)?

Comment: You are clearly picking on me. I have added the DRAE. And I don't believe citing a dictionary definition can be considered plagiarism.This is a ***dictionary***, not writing. The other thing was writing. And tchrist on ELL says the same thing.

Comment: You are doing a disservice to yourself by thinking this is about _you_. No it is not, it is about the content. See how others reference definitions from the DLE in this same question and compare those to your initial version. A valuable and experienced user like you can do better than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94468/discussion-between-lambie-and-fedorqui).

Comment: downvoters: must be bored with nothing to do. If you disagree, take it up with the RAE, not me.

Comment: Esta respuesta es erónea. "En su punto" es "en estado de perfección", no lo que el OP pregunta